# Поиск подстроки в тексте на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В общем написал функцию, которая берет строку случайную из файла:

```
<?php
  $h = fopen('r','file.txt');
  $str = Array();
  while (!EOF)
  {
    $str[] = fgets($h);
  }
  echo $str[rand(0,count($str))];
?>
```

Вот берется любая случайная строка, но если файл большой, там 2,3 гб, естественно, плохо будет. Как лучше исправить, чтобы и при больших размерах файла не засорялась память? 
Вот, что я вычитал про `memory_limit`:

> Эта директива задаёт максимальный
> объём памяти в байтах, который
> разрешается использовать скрипту. Это
> помогает предотвратить ситуацию, при
> которой плохо написанный скрипт
> съедает всю доступную память сервера.
> Для того, чтобы убрать ограничения,
> установите значение этой директивы в
> -1.

Но как его применить, не пойму.

И ещё вопрос. Вот есть такая функция, как поиск строки или текста с использованием регулярных выражений. Я написал скрипт, но он ищет как, то есть, если надо найти в тексте строку `"Привет как дела"`, а в тексте она будет разбита переносом, или иметь запятую, скрипт найдет только полное сходство. Какую функцию использовать или как изменить, чтобы находить строку, слово, которые не имеют полного соответствия.

```
<?php
  $my=$_POST['area'];
  $stroka=$_POST['mytext'];
  if(preg_match("/$stroka/i",$my))
    die("Text -$stroka- detected");
  else {    
    echo "Text -$stroka- not detected";
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
  {
    echo '<a style="margin-right:20px;"
    href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'">
    Назад</a>';
  }
?>
```

Помогите, новичку, пожалуйста, исправить.

Comment: Я извеняюсь вы не 1Сшник случайно?:D<br>
Text -$stroka- not detected...<br>
улыбнуло....

Comment: Ну на учебе я всё изучал)))))))))))))

Comment: @Afimida, Прежде чем нажать "Отправить вопрос" посмотрите, что вы написали. Соответствует ли оно первоначальной идеи.

Comment: Исправил, злой дядя эксперт всё видит. =))

Comment: Ну, например, регуляркой типа `[\W]+($stroka)[\W]+`<br>
Вообще, откровенно говоря, полностью так и не понял сути вопроса и зачем вообще такое делать...

Comment: Ну, к примеру, желаешь ты найти фразу "Привет как дела", а в тексте она написана так "Привет, как дела?"

Comment: если так то<br>

    $data = explode(" ","Привет как дела");
    $preg = "/($data[0][\W]{0,2}$data[1][\W]{0,2}$data[2][\W]+)/";
    //чтото типа такого но это жесть...

Comment: А для чего нам переменная $preg ?

Comment: FAIC PALM... чтобы по ней потом сверять нашу строку *_*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу файла. Нужно сначала посчитать переносы.

```
$h = fopen('r','file.txt');
$str = Array();
//while (!EOF) // <- тут вы загнули конечно
$linesCnt = 0;
while (!feof($h))
{
fgets($h);
$linesCnt ++;
}

//итак, мы имеем количество строк в переменной $linesCnt.
$randLineCnt = rand(0, $linesCnt - 1);
rewind($h); // перематываем указатель на начало (что бы читать файл по новой);

for($i=0; $i < $randLineCnt; $i++) fgets($h);
$randLine = fgets($h);
fclose($h);

// всё. Теперь в переменной $randLine у нас есть рандомная строка. Только если файл действительно будет 2 гб, то выполнятся это будет долго
```

ПО поводу второго:

> > регулярных выражений. Я написал скрипт, но он ищет как, то есть, если надо найти в тексте строку "Привет как дела"...

Вы должны выделить некоторую маску (т.е некоторая часть текста должна быть стабильна) и на основе этой маски составить регулярное выражение.

Например мы хотим выделить часть предложения которое начинается на hi и заканчивается you.

есть текст:

```
"hi, how are

you ?"
```

регулярное выражение будет примерно таким:

```
preg_match('~(hi.*?you)~s')
```

тут мы применили модификатор /s это значит что в . входят также переносы строки

в общим как то так

PS: этот МаркДаун меня не слушается :(

Comment: Списки дичайше напрягают, да. Так и не понял как его закрыть в редакторе.

Comment: А почему не так, например?) fgets читает *строку* и возвращает ее *без переносов*, т.е. регулярка там вообще не в тему.

    while (!feof($h)) {
      fgets($h);
      $linesCnt++;
      }

Comment: это уже ночь... именно так и нужно делать.  Спасибо что поправили.

Comment: Спасибо большое будем разбираться!

Answer (score 0):

Идея конечно так себе, но всё же: если строки в файле 2.3 Гб примерно одинаковой длины, можно сначала получить случайный номер строки, а потом перемотать файл с помощью fseek на примерно эту же строчку.